# Error in Pytorch ax-platform hyperparameters tuning

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I was trying to tune the hyperparameters of the optimizer of my neural network, using the code below, this is my custom dataset loader

```
#Create dataset loader class
class DatasetLoader(Dataset):
    """Face Landmarks dataset."""

    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.all_datas = torch.load(root_dir)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([ 
                                              transforms.ToTensor(),
                                              transforms.Normalize((0.5), (0.5)),])
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.all_datas['images'])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        all_images = self.all_datas['images']
        image = all_images[idx]
        
        all_labels = self.all_datas['labels']
        label = all_labels[idx]
        
        return image, label
```

Split the dataset into training, validation and test

```
#Split data into training data set and testing dataset 
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

batch_size = 512
test_train_split=0.8
val_train_split=0.1

shuffle_dataset = True
random_seed= 42
dataset = DatasetLoader(root_dir='plankton.pt')
# Creating data indices for training and validation splits:
dataset_size = len(dataset)
indices = list(range(dataset_size))
test_split = int(np.floor(test_train_split * dataset_size))
if shuffle_dataset :
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)

train_indices, test_indices = indices[:test_split], indices[test_split:]
train_size = len(train_indices)
validation_split = int(np.floor((1 - val_train_split) * train_size))

train_indices, val_indices = train_indices[ : validation_split], train_indices[validation_split:]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_indices)
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_indices) 

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, 
                                           sampler=train_sampler)
validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                sampler=valid_sampler)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                sampler=test_sampler)
```

Neural network and optimizer

```
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.act1 = nn.Tanh()
    self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.act2 = nn.Tanh()
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8 * 25 *25,100)
    self.act3 = nn.Tanh()
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 12)
 
  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.pool1(self.act1(self.conv1(x)))
    out = self.pool2(self.act2(self.conv2(out)))
    out = out.view(-1, 8 * 25 * 25)  
    out = self.act3(self.fc1(out))
    out = self.fc2(out)
    return out
model = Net()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05,momentum=0.3) 
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Use Ax platform to tune the hyperpaprameters

```
from ax.plot.contour import plot_contour
from ax.plot.trace import optimization_trace_single_method
from ax.service.managed_loop import optimize
from ax.utils.notebook.plotting import render, init_notebook_plotting
from ax.utils.tutorials.cnn_utils import load_mnist, train, evaluate, CNN

init_notebook_plotting(offline=True)

torch.manual_seed(12345)
dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

def train_evaluate(parameterization):
    net = Net()
    net = train(net=net, train_loader=train_loader, parameters=parameterization, dtype=dtype, device=device)
    return evaluate(
        net=net,
        data_loader=validation_loader,
        dtype=dtype,
        device=device,
    )
best_parameters, values, experiment, model = optimize(
    parameters=[
        {"name": "lr", "type": "range", "bounds": [1e-6, 0.4], "log_scale": True},
        {"name": "momentum", "type": "range", "bounds": [0.0, 1.0]},
    ],
    evaluation_function=train_evaluate,
    objective_name='accuracy'
    
)
```

The error

```
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.service.utils.instantiation: Inferred value type of ParameterType.FLOAT for parameter lr. If that is not the expected value type, you can explicity specify 'value_type' ('int', 'float', 'bool' or 'str') in parameter dict.
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.service.utils.instantiation: Inferred value type of ParameterType.FLOAT for parameter momentum. If that is not the expected value type, you can explicity specify 'value_type' ('int', 'float', 'bool' or 'str') in parameter dict.
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.service.utils.instantiation: Created search space: SearchSpace(parameters=[RangeParameter(name='lr', parameter_type=FLOAT, range=[1e-06, 0.4], log_scale=True), RangeParameter(name='momentum', parameter_type=FLOAT, range=[0.0, 1.0])], parameter_constraints=[]).
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.modelbridge.dispatch_utils: Using Bayesian optimization since there are more ordered parameters than there are categories for the unordered categorical parameters.
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.modelbridge.dispatch_utils: Using Bayesian Optimization generation strategy: GenerationStrategy(name='Sobol+GPEI', steps=[Sobol for 5 trials, GPEI for subsequent trials]). Iterations after 5 will take longer to generate due to  model-fitting.
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.service.managed_loop: Started full optimization with 20 steps.
[INFO 03-18 11:05:26] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 1...
[ERROR 03-18 11:05:29] ax.service.managed_loop: expected scalar type Long but found Float
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ax/utils/common/executils.py", line 169, in handle_exceptions_in_retries
    yield  # Perform action within the context manager.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ax/utils/common/executils.py", line 147, in actual_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ax/service/managed_loop.py", line 206, in run_trial
    for arm, weight in self._get_weights_by_arm(trial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ax/service/managed_loop.py", line 206, in <dictcomp>
    for arm, weight in self._get_weights_by_arm(trial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ax/service/managed_loop.py", line 144, in _call_evaluation_function
    evaluation = self.evaluation_function(parameterization)
  File "<ipython-input-71-6d534bbe15a5>", line 3, in train_evaluate
    net = train(net=net, train_loader=train_loader, parameters=parameterization, dtype=dtype, device=device)
```

However,if i change dtype from float to long like below:

```
dtype = torch.long
```

The error became:

```
TypeError: nn.Module.to only accepts floating point or complex dtypes, but got desired dtype=torch.int64
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try torch.long() ?

Comment: @Joe I tried torch.long(), it gave me error 'TypeError: 'torch.dtype' object is not callable'

Comment: What if you do Net().long where you assign net?

Comment: @Joe I don't think it worked either 'AttributeError: 'Net' object has no attribute 'long'
'